# Sorting data in Rails by own SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, filter, grid, netzke

I'm working on a Rails application with gem Netzke.
I have *GridPanel* from *Netzke::Basepack* with my own buttons. How do I make actions for them to filter the table of GridPanel **by my own SQL query**?
I tried to make filtering like this:

```
def configure(c)
  super
  c.model = "Artist"
  c.columns = [{ name: "name", filter_with: lambda{|rel, value, op| rel.where("name like ? ", "Scorpions") } }]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `filter_with` on a specific column is not probably what you need. Try using the `scope` option on the grid instead:

```
def configure(c)
  super
  c.model = "Artist"
  c.scope = ->(rel) { rel.where("name like ?", "Scorpions") }
end
```